# How to select file paths for specific extension using the regex

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

could you please help me to solve following regex problem (for Python environment)?

```
a string = hfhfdgdx:\sdfsdfs\Pending\1\sfsdf\sdfsd\eewrwe.movRTrdgdgdgdfx:\sdfsdfs\Pending\2\sfsdf\sdfsd\eewrwe.3gpGFDSDSx:\sdfsdfs\Pending\3\sfsdf\sdfsd\eewrwe.m2etdfgdf

regex pattern = \\Pending(.*?\\)*(?=.*m2et)
```

start of selection with `"\Pending"`, select all until the last `"\"` for the m2et extension. But it starts with the first `"'\"` and ends with the last `"\"` for the m2et `(\Pending\1\sfsdf\sdfsd\eewrwe.movRTrdgdgdgdfx:\sdfsdfs\Pending\2\sfsdf\sdfsd\eewrwe.3gpGFDSDSx:\sdfsdfs\Pending\3\sfsdf\sdfsd\).` 
I would like to select only path for the m2et `(\Pending\3\sfsdf\sdfsd\)`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\\Pending\\(?:(?!\bPending\b).)*\\)(?=[^\\]*m2et)
```

You will have to negate `Pending` in lookahead for that.

See Demo.

https://regex101.com/r/ota4md/2

Comment: Thanks again, vks. but there is one more problem: when the regex is applied for a string where "m2ts" appears more time it will select text until last "\" which can be outside the "\Pending..." path. Some example text: VALUE="AAAAA\BBBBB\CCCCC\Pending\DDDDD\20160604170127.m2ts"/&gt;&lt;PARAM NAME="AEFF_VIDEO_USERDATA_AUTO_FIX_FLAG" VALUETYPE="UNSI\GNED_INT" VALUE="0"/&gt;&lt;PARAM VALUE="20160604093325.m2ts"
Only "\Pending'DDDDD\" should be selected, but in this case "\Pending\DDDDD\20160604170127.m2ts"/&gt;&lt;PARAM NAME="AEFF_VIDEO_USERDATA_AUTO_FIX_FLAG" VALUETYPE="UNSI\" is selected.

Comment: Thank vks. It was really so quick solution. Really appreciate it.